# Retrieve array over $http and view in ion-item of ion-list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Like the title says, I'm trying to assign a list from a $http request and then see that list in a view.

I believe the problem is the view is shown before the data loads, if I understand ionic correctly. And the view is never updated when the variables change.

I'm told resolves are one way of fixing this but I'd prefer for the view to change and then show a loading indicator while it waits for the http request to finish, and then show the list.

Thanks!

Edit: I think I need to add the way I'm loading the data is through ng-init in the html file, which seems wrong too. Is there a better way altogether?

view html file:

```
<ion-view view-title={{ListName}} ng-init="getList()">
    <ion-content ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in list"
                      class="item-thumbnail-left">

                {{item.id}}
               <img ng-src="{{item.thumbnail}}">
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller snippet:

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.list = []
  $scope.ListName = ''


  $scope.getList = function(){
     $scope.ListName = 'list'

     $scope.list = [{id: 1, thumbnail:null}, {id: 2, thumbnail:null},{id: 3, thumbnail:null} ,{id: 4, thumbnail:null}]

}

})
```

the list is actually gotten in a http request that returns a promise but this gives me the same problem. It's something annoyingly basic that I just don't understand about ionic yet

Comment: could you add a plnkr or fiddle so that one could look at the code

Comment: I added some code for you to review. Thanks!

Comment: how does the ion-view find `getList()` ?

Comment: Because it's in the ng-controller ListCtrl.

Comment: The controller association does not automatically extend to an element's parents. You probably need to invoke `getList()` as part of controller initialization.

Comment: getList() does run with the code shown

Comment: hmm.. if you were to say print on console the scope id, then you have a better idea if the list is being generated in the specific controller object you want. You can also modify the html to include id so that you can correlate easily

Comment: Of course I've printed to the console. that works as expected. The only problem is ionic isn't displaying my list. initializing something to list other than [] will show that list but it's useless for my purposes

Comment: It works for me only if I do one of two things. Either move the ng-controller attribute to ion-view, or explicitly initialize the list in controller by calling getList(). Could you post a plunkr - so much easier.

Comment: either use timeout in your http request or if you will be working with such big data you need to use resolve, thus while the data is being loaded, you can show spinner or what you wish using the `$ionicLoading` feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dinesh answered my question. Putting the ng-controller in the ion-view was all I needed to do!